# Input/output error without disk failure

Tags: python, filesystem, ext4, ls

1 month ago I ran a python program on my ubuntu server which downloaded videos and cut them into images. I used urlretrieve to download the files and then I used opencv to cut them into single frames:

```
def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
    readsofar = blocknum * blocksize
    if totalsize > 0:
        percent = readsofar * 1e2 / totalsize
        s = "\r%5.1f%% %*d / %d" % (
            percent, len(str(totalsize)), readsofar, totalsize)
        sys.stderr.write(s)
        if readsofar >= totalsize: # near the end
            sys.stderr.write("\n")
    else: # total size is unknown
        sys.stderr.write("read %d\n" % (readsofar,))


def vid_cut(base_path, video, video_id):
    print("\nstart cutting: " + str(video))
    path = base_path + "/" + video_id
    name_video = os.listdir(path)[0]
    video_path = os.path.join(path, name_video)
    # Path to video file
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    frame_count = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    if fps != 0:
        duration = frame_count/fps
        picture_folder = path + "/pictures"
        os.mkdir(picture_folder)
        # Used as counter variable
        count = 0

        # checks whether frames were extracted
        success = True
        while success:
            # vidObj object calls read
            # function extract frames
            vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, (count * 500))
            success, image = vidcap.read()

            # Saves the frames with frame-count
            if success:
                cv2.imwrite(picture_folder + "/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)

                count += 1
            if (count/2 > duration):
                success = False
        vidcap.release()
        os.remove(video_path)
        original = path
        target = base_path + "/fertig/" + video_id
        shutil.move(original, target)
        print("\nvideo done: " + str(video))


# Driver Code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_path = "/media/hdd/videos" #Wohin gedownloadet werden soll

    all_videos = pickle.load(open("videos.pkl", "rb"))

    for video in all_videos:
        video_id = str(video[0])
        download_link = video[1]
        print("starting: ", video)
        video_slug = video[1]
        path_video = base_path + "downloads" + "/" + video_id
        os.mkdir(path_video)
        urlretrieve(download_link, path_video + "/a.mp4", reporthook)
        print("\nDownloading abgeschlossen: ", video)

        vid_cut(base_path + "downloads", video, video_id)
```

suddenly the program exited because the module os experienced an input/output error. I also could not access the filesystem with ls. After searching online the most probable issue seemed to be a drive failure. I just bought the drive 2 month ago, nontheless I run e2fsck with -c -c. No errors were found. I reformatted the drive and started the program again. Now I get the input/output error again. Any advice?

Edit:
stat -f . returns

```
File: "."
    ID: e94de2b03a229ef9 Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 1211023539 Free: 622285068  Available: 561234266
Inodes: Total: 152616960  Free: 145572533
```

I guess the inodes are not the problem

Edit 2:
I received Errno 5, I ran the python program from the command line over screen. I detached screen with ctrl a + d and clossed the ssh connection to the server. This issue happened after a few days of running the program continuously.

Edit 3:
I do not know how to read kernel/system logs. However the cpu which is installed is a Ryzen 7900x. I explicitly wanted to monitor temperature therefore I upgraded the default linux kernel to 6.6.1. I do not know whether this could have caused any issues. However a can confirm that the cpu temp never exceeded 80 degrees C in a 5 minute interval.

Smartctl output for the hdd:

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.6.1Sensors_Kernel-sensorskernel] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD50NMZW-59BCBS0
Serial Number:    ***
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 26a11913b
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    5,000,947,523,584 bytes [5.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    4800 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Dec 25 18:40:18 2023 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 3840) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 242) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30b5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4175
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       58
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       423
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       21
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       179
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   119   109   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

``
```

Comment: Very high number of files created? Run out of i-nodes?

Comment: yes, but how can I check whether I run out of i-nodes and how can I prevent this?

Comment: An `errno` is usually printed with that kind of error ... What is the error number and exact error message? ... Are you running this script in the background? How are you running it (exact commandline) ... Does this issue happen immediately or after a while? Do you run it from the terminal? do you keep the terminal open or detach the process and close the terminal? ... etc. please.

Comment: That is a SDIN/STDOUT/STDERR related input/output kind and not the disk operation kind ... Most likely because the process can't output to terminal at some point ... You can either redirect output streams inside your python script or redirect the whole script output in the shell ... Alternatively you can improve your script so it doesn't print to terminal (including errors)

Comment: @Raffa the program has now exited. still I cannot access the folder on the hard drive anymore with plain old ls.

Comment: Are you using the same screen/terminal? Do you get normal behavior if you use a new terminal? ... You can try running your script with redirection of `stdout` and `stderr` like so: `./script.py > /dev/null 2>&1` or to a file if you like and see if it helps to rule out this part.

Comment: I mean the reason of this issue is (as it seems) that your python process couldn't print to terminal anymore at some point ... So, what makes `ls` or any other process special ... In other words, the problem might persist so you might need to open a new terminal and if `ls` can output to the new terminal, then this most likely proves the standard I/O streams in the terminal hypothesis I think.

Comment: @Raffa I disconnected from ssh, reconnected and still cannot access the folder on the hdd with ls. Even if I use a new screen instance I still get a input/output error when using ls.

Comment: OK, fair enough. This now is drifting towards more being  not directly related to your script but rather to hardware/filesystem/connectivity ... Considering you have done filesystem checks and you tend to believe your disk is okay as well and considering that you seem to be using an external storage disk/media, I would consider connectivity issues like mounting/unmounting USB/IDE cables external disk power supply/current or disk sleep/spin down/power saving settings also kernel driver/module support for type of connection/data transfer etc. ... A good  look at the kernel/system logs might help

Comment: Are any firmware updates offered for the drive/(motherboard)? Could excess heat be a problem?  From the smartmontools package, try running sudo smartctl -a /dev/<whatever> and add that to your original posting.

Answer (score 0):

Check filesystem status, including free inodes:

`$ stat -f .`  # where `.` is for 'current dir'.

More info: `man stat`

More about inodes; Ref:
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/linux/inode-count/
https://www.stackscale.com/blog/inodes-linux/